# Georgian language in Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, georgian

When I get String from a server the Georgian language shows as squares on Android version 2.3. The solution to get it from strings.xml doesn't work as I don't know what am I expecting from the server. So is there any solution to format it from code and get it to show the proper symbols. On newer versions of Android it works fine. The string is displayed without problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get from a server"? It may be that the encoding in that server request/response is wrong ...

Comment: Pretty sure it's an encoding problem. Check if the server is actually responding with UTF-8.

Comment: Well on Android with versions above 4.2 it works fine. It displays the proper symbols.

Comment: How do you fetch the language? Google tends to change the network code from time to time which could lead to such version differences.